# Случайный лес и бэггинг деревьев решений

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, dataframe, numpy

Запрограммировала случайный лес и бэггинг деревьев решений.

Что-то видимо не правильно потому, что процент несовпадений выдает одинаковое число для трех методов, и при изменении выборки ничего не происходит.

Как правильно должна выглядеть программа? Надо ли отдельно реализовать бэггинг и деревья решений?

Код:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
 from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier
 from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Vika\\Downloads\\1500.csv', ";",decimal =',', skipinitialspace=True)
 data.head()
 kfold = 10
 itog_val1 = {} 
 itog_val2 = {} 
 itog_val3 = {} 
 itog_val4 = {} 
 itog_val5 = {} 
 itog_val6 = {}
 X = data.drop('Y1', axis=1).values[:, :8] 
 y = data['Y1'].values
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
 print ('обучающая выборка X:\n', X_train[:6])
 print ('\n')
 print ('y_train У:\n', y_train[:10])
 print (' \n')
 print ('тестовая выборка Х:\n', X_test[:6])
 print ('\n')
 print ('y_test У\n', y_test[:10])
 first_tree = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)  
 scores = cross_val_score(first_tree, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold) 
 itog_val1 = scores 
 print(itog_val1)  
 first_tree1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)    
 scores = cross_val_score(first_tree, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
 itog_val4 = scores 
 print(itog_val4)
 first_tree.fit(X_train, y_train) 
 first_tree.score(X_test, y_test)
 y_test_predicted = first_tree.predict(X_test) 
 print ('RandomForestClassifier X\n', X_test[:9])
 print ('\n')
 print ('RandomForestClassifier y\n', y_test[:11]) 
 first_tree1.fit(X_train, y_train)
 first_tree1.score(X_test, y_test)
 y_test_predicted = first_tree1.predict(X_test)
 print ('DecisionTreeClassifier X\n', X_test[:9])
 print ('\n')
 print (' DecisionTreeClassifier y\n', y_test[:11])
 first_bagging.fit(X_train, y_train)
 first_bagging.score(X_test, y_test)
 y_test_predicted = first_bagging.predict(X_test)
 print ('BaggingClassifier X\n', X_test[:9])
 print ('\n')
 print (' BaggingClassifier y\n', y_test[:11])
 res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
               columns=['Y1','YR'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
 (res['Y1']!= res['YR']).mean()
 res1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
               columns=['Y1','YD'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
 (res1['Y1']!= res1['YD']).mean() 
 res2 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
               columns=['Y1','YB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
 (res2['Y1']!= res2['YB']).mean()
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что что-то неправильно?

Comment: потому что процент несовпадений выдает одинаковое число, для трех методов, и при изменении выборки , ничего не происходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы создали три DataFrame из одних и тех же данных:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
                   columns=['Y1','YR'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
...
res1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
                    columns=['Y1','YD'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
...
res2 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
                    columns=['Y1','YB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
```

как следствие процент несовпадений - одинаковый

Comment: И снова спасибо) Вы лучший

Comment: @user280357, всегда рад помочь :)